# use telepot (telegram bot python package) through socks5 proxy

Tags: python, proxy, bots, telegram

i want to test my telegram bot on localhost with flask
i use telepot and need to set socks5 proxy for connection but telepot only accept Http proxy by default , is there any way to use socks5 proxy instead of Http ?

```
from flask import Flask
import telepot
app = Flask(__name__)
telepot.api.set_proxy('localhost:port')


@app.route("/")
def updates():
    token = "token"
    telegramBot = telepot.Bot(token)
    return telegramBot.getUpdates()
```

Answer (score 1):

Here some PRs with socks support: 
https://github.com/nickoala/telepot/pull/386
https://github.com/nickoala/telepot/pull/389